# I have a .txt file and I should scroll and print each element on the screen (list of strings)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a .txt file and I should scroll and print each element on the screen (list of strings).
I am new and inexperienced, can you please help me write the file ndex.cshtml (view)?

(Class.cs)

```
public class Reader
{
    public static List<string> Read(string path)
     {
            var result = new List<string>();
            String line;

        try
            { 
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
                {
                    result.Add(line);
                    line = sr.ReadLine();

            }
            }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result = new List<string>();
        }
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

}

(HomeController.cs)
{

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var result = Reader.Reader.Read("......txt");
      
        return View(result);
    }
```

Comment: You can not print the element. you need to fetch and read each line of a text file.

Comment: from a block box test view point, seems no difference between display each lines, and display the whole text?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to render the view...

#### View.cshtml

You can specify a List as your type of model if you wish instead of introducing your own abstractions.  Here is a [partial view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-6.0):

```
@model List<string>

@{
    Layout = null;
}


<ul>
@{
    foreach (string line in Model)
    {
        <li>@line</li>
    }
}
</ul>
```

In the razor view you can iterate through the strings in the `foreach`.  Here I'm putting the output in an unordered list.

You can add c# code to execute in the view using the `@` blocks.  `@{ }` will put in a block of code to execute.

#### Reading text file

You can also read all lines from the text file using:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"...filename.txt");
```

Putting the full path to the filename.  Then you could change your type of model to `Enumerable<string>` as we are only enumerating through the collection.

Comment: string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"...filename.txt");

Comment: where should i enter it?

Comment: the line should be in contrller. it's a simpler replacement for your long `Read` method.

Comment: thank you very much, but it's not working at the moment

Comment: Thanks so much! For real! I finally succeeded with Andez's code, I just had to handle the exception in the model class.

Comment: With that in mind, I would now have to create a model class with the details of the different universities to take the strings that.txt (name, address, coordinates) and then display them on a map via Google.
You can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I just created a demo project in [github](https://github.com/LeiYangGH/aspnetcore-show-text-lines), to display text lines in html. The OP also mentioned scroll and print, but that should be considered only **after succcesfully display** those lines. So this demo can be a start for the OP.
Also paste main code here. I'm using [Razor pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

- Code behind

```cs
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        //other lines...
        public string[] Lines { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            // you need change the fullName, and may need some exception handling
            string fullName = Path.Combine(_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "js/site.js");
            Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fullName);
        }
    }
```

- Razor

```cs
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">This is text lines</h1>
    @foreach (string line in @Model.Lines)
    {
        <p>@line</p>
        @*add a hr to distinguish lines*@
        <hr />
    }
</div>
```